# Xcode 5 - Required plug-in not present in DVTPlugInCompatibilityUUIDs?

Tags: iphone, xcode, xcode5

After upgrading Xcode to v5.0.1, I started receiving following warning in terminal when trying to run git commands inside project folder:

> [MT] PluginLoading: Required plug-in compatibility UUID
>   37B30044-3B14-46BA-ABAA-F01000C27B63 for plug-in at path
>   '~/Library/Application
>   Support/Developer/Shared/Xcode/Plug-ins/Unity4XC.xcplugin' not present
>   in DVTPlugInCompatibilityUUIDs

I am not getting any warning inside Xcode and the project is compiling just fine but there must be a reason. Any ideas why is this happening and how to fix it?

Comment: I got a very similar error just now when going from Xcode 6.? to 6.2: `2015-03-10 15:54:48.219 xcodebuild[10278:259521] [MT] PluginLoading: Required plug-in compatibility UUID A16FF353-8441-459E-A50C-B071F53F51B7 for plug-in at path '~/Library/Application Support/Developer/Shared/Xcode/Plug-ins/Unity4XC.xcplugin' not present in DVTPlugInCompatibilityUUIDs`

Answer (score 141, accepted):

I modified a shell commands I found [here](https://github.com/benoitsan/BBUncrustifyPlugin-Xcode/issues/23) to fix this for all my plugins.

To fix this issue:

```bash
XCODEUUID=`defaults read /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Info DVTPlugInCompatibilityUUID`
for f in ~/Library/Application\ Support/Developer/Shared/Xcode/Plug-ins/*; do defaults write "$f/Contents/Info" DVTPlugInCompatibilityUUIDs -array-add $XCODEUUID; done
```

Comment: This worked for me when my builds were complaining about `OMQuickHelp.xcplugin`

Comment: Not working for me, I got this error: `defaults[13832:169900] Could not write domain /Users/username/Library/Application Support/Developer/Shared/Xcode/Plug-ins/Unity4XC.xcplugin/Contents/Info; exiting`

Comment: If this doesn't work for you, it might be that your plugin is just a broken link which needs to be removed - that's what I had, a link to an old Unity installation that wasn't there anymore.

Comment: If I create an alias to this in .bashrc e.g. `alias xcodeplugins='XCODEUUID=\`defaults read` etc, I get syntax error near unexpected token \`defaults'. Any tips?

Comment: had to make a modification due to having a non-standard xcode install path. This worked for me: `XCODEUUID=$(defaults read "$(xcode-select -p)/../Info" DVTPlugInCompatibilityUUID);
for f in ~/Library/Application\ Support/Developer/Shared/Xcode/Plug-ins/*; do
    defaults write "$f/Contents/Info" DVTPlugInCompatibilityUUIDs -array-add $XCODEUUID; 
done`

Comment: @DavidJames if you haven't gotten the alias working yet, you'd need to make these 2 lines a function and then call that function as an alias. Here's my code (and BTW this solution worked perfectly using Xcode 7.3.1)

`alias fixXcodePlugins=fixXcodePluginsFunc`

`fixXcodePluginsFunc() {
  XCODEUUID=\`defaults read /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Info DVTPlugInCompatibilityUUID\``

  `for f in ~/Library/Application\ Support/Developer/Shared/Xcode/Plug-ins/*; do defaults write "$f/Contents/Info" DVTPlugInCompatibilityUUIDs -array-add $XCODEUUID; done
}`

Comment: You might need to replace 'defaults write' with 'sudo defaults write', depending on where the plugins are located.

Comment: Thanks !! Worked for me too with Xcode 9. Mine was complaining FuzzyAutocomplete.xcplugin' not present in DVTPlugInCompatibilityUUIDs

Comment: did not get what is the issue but by following your steps, It works.

Answer (score 44):

Try to do : *`xcode-select --install`*. It resolved my problem

Comment: After updating to macOS Sierra and Xcode 8.0 the plugins stopped working. This answer solved the problem.

Comment: doesn't work in new xcode if your tools are already installed.

Comment: There's a new tool out. Try `softwareupdate --list` worst case you can do `softwareupdate -a`

Comment: Worked!! Thanks a million.

Answer (score 31):

In my case of Xcode 7, remove all Xcode plugins fixed my issue.

```
rm -rf ~/Library/Application\ Support/Developer/Shared/Xcode/Plug-ins/*
```

Comment: This did it for me as well!

Comment: I suspect your `DVTPlugInCompatibilityUUID` key in `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Info.plist` may still have the stale UUIDs listed there even if you delete the underlying plugins. That was the case for me with an ancient plugin from 2013 that was no longer working, so I opened the plist in XCode and deleted the value from that key.

Comment: Worked like a charm!

Comment: Worked for me as well 2020

Comment: Selected answer didn't work but this worked. 2021 XCode 12.5.1

Answer (score 6):

I believe the issue is that you have an Xcode plugin installed that has a missing (or has an incorrect) `DVTPlugInCompatibilityUUIDs` key-value pair in its plist file. See what this plugin did to solve it: https://github.com/gfontenot/XVim/commit/35bbf24bc074e330a9bea852c190d8fdcbfff1ea

Maybe check if your plugin (looks like it's for Unity) has an updated version.

Comment: if there isnt one, just open the bundle and edit the info plist and it works again

Answer (score 0):

I had deleted unity from my machine. After installing unity the builds worked for me. I was trying to build an app using robovm.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it is a bit late, but I had just to restart Xcode after an Xcode update and press the install components button when it showed up. Then my git problems were gone.